# LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE issue when using Dropzone uploading multiple files with node multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropzone.js, multer, busboy

Using Dropzone in the frontend to upload multiple files to the server in one request and using the [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware to handle multipart/form-data. Set `uploadMultiple: true` in the Dropzone config, it will append [] to the name. For example, the name would be files[0], files[1](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) etc.

The server side codes:

```
var uploader = multer({dest: dest});
router.post(url, uploader.array('files', 30), function(req, res) {
   ...
});
```

However, seems multer().array(fieldname) only allows the fieldname matches the name in the form data. Otherwise, it throws LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE error.

Any suggestions to fix it by making the name always as 'fields' instead of appending [] or making the multer to handle different names like that?

Answer (score 2):

In your cases input attribute name on client side must be "files".

```
<input type="file" name="files" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Under the Dropzone configuration, set *paramName* to a function that returns the name:

```
Dropzone.options.mainDropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    paramName: function(){
        return "files";
    },
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews"
}
```

Make sure to use the same name that the function returns on the server side:

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
}).array('files', 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`files.map(file => formData.append(`files`, file))`